# Does ":norm! @q" use mapped keys inside the macro?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode, macro

The documentation for `:norm[al][!]` states that "mappings will not be used" when the `!` is written.

Consider the following setup commands:

```
:nnoremap \c Chello<esc>
:let @q = '\cIthis is a contrived example: ' . "\<esc>"
:%norm! @q
```

Will the `<leader>c` mapping be applied each time the `q` macro is executed? Or are *all* user mappings disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, mappings inside the macro are still applied as normal.

For example, apply the commands in the question to the file:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

The output will be:

```
this is a contrived example: hello
this is a contrived example: hello
this is a contrived example: hello
this is a contrived example: hello
```

Which indicates that the `\c` mapping was used when the macro was executed.